Female comedian, early 1990s on HBO
I need the name of the female comedian who did a stand-up comedy special on HBO in the early 1990s.  She was a thin brunette with curly hair, blue eyes.  A big part of her routine was  a bit where she explained how her husband had a condition called  "left".  At the end of the special she had her dog come out and bark "HBO" for the audience.  She spoke somewhat softly and did not use much profanity.  She looked to be in her thirties- early forties.

Could this be Rita Rudner?

Her first solo HBO special Rita Rudner's One Night Stand premiered on
  March 29th 1989. It was nominated for two Cable Ace Awards. By 1990,
  Rudner had won the 1990 American Comedy Award for Funniest Female
  Stand-Up Comic and stared in her second award-winning HBO special Born
  To Be Mild.
[...]
Her cable specials continued with [...] her next solo HBO special
  Married Without Children.


I don't know the specific routine that the OP describes, but this was certainly who came to mind based on his description.

She's brunette and definitely speaks softly. Good pull.

FWIW, Rudner sometimes performed with her dog Bonkers who did tricks.
